# Not getting how to call the my callbackurl with recharge vendor api

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, api, callback

am developing one recharge and money transfer portal using c#, asp.net, due to so many transactions am planning to quit timing in waiting for response from api

1) from front end i have to call the transactions 
2) response of perticular api should update in backend

i heard that callback url we can use  my api vendor given like api to request

***string URL ="?member_id="abcde"&api_password="12345"&number="someething"***

In the above code where i have call the my api to get response, am not getting please help me

i created from my end one HttpPost call back method to accept the response,but not getting how to hit

Comment: firstly, u cant put 1& 2 both parallel because if the response from api is negative or unsuccessful then the user might not know that.

Comment: use webclient or rstclient to create a request and see the method the request(get or post) and then try to use method webclient.downloadstring or restclient.execute

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/19SZlsHF-CMd6Po6FvwnfMFboUqBJvt_kYoXpwBQINTE/edit?usp=sharing